# Restore and Exclude from Scanning are grayed (disabled) in NOD32 Smart Security 4

Tags: nod32

I am using NOD32 Smart Security 4.2.71.2, fully updated. The "Restore And Exclude from Scanning" option, when I right-click on a quarantined item, is disable. How can I fix that?

Comment: It may be that the file is too high-risk to be recovered, or that you're not running in the highest privileges. Since you failed to provide any information about your computer and operating system, we can't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation for [ESS quarantine](http://help.eset.com/ess/8/en-US/idh_page_quarantine.htm) states:

> #### Restoring from Quarantine
>
> Quarantined files can also be restored to their original location. Use the Restore feature for this purpose, which is available from the context menu by right-clicking a given file in the Quarantine window. **If a file is marked as potentially unwanted application, the Restore and exclude from scanning option is enabled.** Read more about this type of application in the glossary. The context menu also offers the Restore to... option which allows you to restore a file to a location other than the one from which it was deleted.

The `Restore and exclude from scanning` option is available only for [potentially unwanted applications](http://help.eset.com/ess/8/en-US/idh_unwanted_application.htm).